# SQL Server 2008 : cursor to retrieve and replace data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

Maybe there's a better way about this but this has to be somewhat dynamic.

From a vb.net form I need to restore or replace data from one table to another. The two tables are identical except for a couple different columns.

First I wrote some SQL to grab the column names of the table passed in. Then through ordinal position I get only the tables I want values from. I store these tables names in a temp table.

Now I want to get those values from the backup table using the temp table column names and place them in the master table.

So I guess I suppose I need a cursor to loop through in some way.. I haven't touched a cursor since college and wow.

I'll embarrass myself and post my current code.

```
SET @getColCURSOR = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT name
    FROM #MyTempTable --created previously as table only holding column names

OPEN @getColCURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM @getColCURSOR 
INTO @columnName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    select @columnName --this variable should as a column name and change 
    from AUDIT_TABLE a where a.ID = 7 -- 7 is just for testing is dynamic variable
  FETCH NEXT FROM @getColCURSOR 
INTO @columnName 
END 

CLOSE @getColCURSOR 
DEALLOCATE @getColCURSOR
```

Comment: It is difficult to tell what you're asking. Please expand upon "I need to restore or replace data from one table to another" with table definitions and example data.

Comment: show us your audit table structure and your main table struture. CAn your audit table include multiple records for the same id?

Comment: the audit table is basically a backup of each table (i.e. triggers track changes).  Each audit table has a self incrimenting PK, inside is the primary key for the table it backs up.  The form I'm gives you a drop down for the table and displays columns in a datagridview.  On selection you capture various data to send to the query/stored procs to restore changes where a user may have did something.. stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to comment on whether this could be done without a cursor, since I'm a bit lost on what you're trying to do. But one issue with your cursor is that you can't parameterize a column name in a `select` statement. So you'll need to replace this:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    select @columnName --this variable should as a column name and change 
    from AUDIT_TABLE a where a.ID = 7 -- 7 is just for testing is dynamic variable
  FETCH NEXT FROM getColCURSOR 
INTO @columnName 
END
```

--with dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    set @SQL =
      N'select ' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ' from AUDIT_TABLE a where a.ID = 7'
    EXEC (@SQL); --w/o brackets assumes you've calling a stored proc
  FETCH NEXT FROM getColCURSOR 
INTO @columnName 
END
```

That could possibly introduce other issues, since dynamic SQL statements execute in their own scope. I'd definitely encourage you to look into whether there's a set-based solution to this, since using dynamic SQL will make this even messier, and I don't think you'll be able to escape dynamic SQL if you want to use a variable for column names.

Comment: can you see a reason why I would be receives far to many records?  I'm getting the correct columns and info.. but it's repeated far to many times.. I'll have to a count(*) to figure out how many..but quite a few.

Comment: Is each individual `select` returning too many records, or are the selects being repeated multiple times?

Comment: selects are being repeated multiple times, going to run a couple of test now.

Comment: actually I think I solved the issue.. I believe by inserting duplicate info into the temp table without cleaning up.  Thus to many records in a persisting temp table.  After recreation I'm all good. Thanx.